# Angular4, Materials and Angular4

Tags: angular, animation

Is anyone able to get Angular4, Material and Animations (required for menus) to work with Visual Studio Code.

Start by downloading from github:
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git

open in VS Code, compile and run, it works.

Now install Material2 (2.0.0-beta.8) using NPM

now import angular animations

and boom - nothing compiles and welcome to node-package hell.

I have yet to find anywhere that can demonstrate how to do this

Help would be great.

**More information**

**installing:**

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

npm install --save @angular/animations
```

and systemjs.config

```
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
  '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',

  '@angular/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.min.js',
  '@angular/animations/browser':'node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js'
```

** npm start**

The Errors (some of them)

```
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button-toggle/button-toggle.d.ts(32,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdButtonToggleGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdButtonToggleGroup'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button-toggle/button-toggle.d.ts(32,50): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdButtonToggleGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button-toggle/button-toggle.d.ts(91,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdButtonToggleGroupMultiple' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdButtonToggleGroupMultiple'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button-toggle/button-toggle.d.ts(91,58): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdButtonToggleGroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(55,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdButton'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(55,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdButton'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(55,39): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & (new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdButtonBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(55,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
```

Comment: I'd recommend using [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create your project - the quickstart project isn't very good, and I think they stopped recommending it in favor of the CLI in the most recent update to the website. That aside, I'd recommend reading the [Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md) guide on the Angular Material GitHub if you haven't already.

Comment: What errors do you get when compiling?  How are you importing material and animations?

Comment: Make sire yoir also install material cdk, follow this tutorial and it should work: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md

Comment: @user2739963 Update all the packages to latest version by using this command npm-check-updates after that enter ncu -a. Remove Node_modules folder and reinstall again. This will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this link http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.sg/2017/05/setting-up-angular-2-in-visual-studio.html giving you a clear way how to use angular in Visual Studio.
Though it is for Angular2.However it is the same for Angular4 no changes

Answer (score 0):

Update the material version which is compactable to the angular version.This will resolve this issue.